# Force reload changes on a component JSwing

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application

I made a code to delete the adobe directories from an user profile, I use it remotely conecting to remote computers. In this code when a file it's deleted an textArea must show the rute of the deleted file. In a System.out.println the rute it runs but it doesn't change the textArea until the recursive function ends.

I have this code. (Sorry for the rudimentary translate to English)

```
private void RecursiveDel(String rute) {
        File tdel = new File(rute);
        if (tdel.isDirectory()) {
            for (File del : tdel.listFiles()) {
                RecursiveDel(del.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        txtInform += "Removing: " + ruta + "\r\n";
        ActRes();
        tdel.delete();
        System.out.println(rute);
        if (tdel.exists()) {
            txtInforme += "File isn't deleted: \r\n" + ruta + "\r\n";
            ActRes();
            Correct = false;
        }
    }
    private void ActRes(){
        Thread act = new Thread(new  Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                txtResult.setText(txtInforme);
            }
        });
        act.start();
    }
```

How I can do show the deleted Files into the TextArea meanwile the recursive function works?

Answer (score 2):

> it runs but it doesn't change the textArea until the recursive function ends.

Correct, because your code is looping through all the directories and building a string rather than trying to update the text area for each directory.

Instead you should be using a `SwingWorker` and "publishing" the directory as you find it. Then every time you publish a value the text area can be updated.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Tasks That Have Interim Results](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for an example of this approach.